# How does HSAV ETF convert interest income into capital gains income? (canada)

Tags: canada, etf, interest, money-market

I came across this ETF Fund from Horizons called [HSAV](https://horizonsetfs.com/ETF/hsav/#at-a-glance), which invests the money across Canadian bank high interest savings accounts. Rather than redistribute interests like a money market fund, the gain in value is reflected in the increasing NAV price.

Now, if I parked money into my chosen high-interest savings account at a local bank, at the end of year, I would have to pay income tax on *interest income*. This fund seems to have *somehow* found a legal way to redistribute similar interest income into a form that can be realized as capital gains on disposition (by increasing the NAV) instead. What sort of accounting mechanism is at play here?

(interest income tax is taxable at the marginal rate, but only 50% of capital gain income is taxable)

From the [product sheet](https://horizonsetfs.com/wp-content/product-sheets/EN/HSAV-Product-Sheet.pdf?ver=1681799443):

> Corporate Class: Tax Efficiency
> HSAV is a class of shares in a corporate class structure that allows the ETF to deliver its returns in a tax-efficient manner. With this structure, the ETF will receive interest income on its cash deposits and that value will be reflected in the daily NAV of the ETF.
>
> However,
> investors in HSAV are not expected to receive any taxable distributions from the ETF.
> This makes the ETF advantageous, particularly if its shares are held in a taxable
> account, where tax on interest income could potentially be in excess of 50%,
> depending on the marginal tax rate of the investor. **With this ETF structure, investors
> can potentially defer incurring a tax liability until they sell the shares of ETF, at which point they may realize a taxable gain.**

Comment: as it says, you aren't receiving any interest income so you don't pay any interest income tax. The value of your shares is going up, so you may pay a capital gains tax when you sell them, which is what you normally pay when the value of your shares goes up and you sell them. Now, why *they* don't have to pay interest income tax, I don't know.

Comment: @user253751 exactly. they seem to have invented this financial vehicle that converts interest income into capital gains. I’d be interested in doing the same thing for gains vs dividends. those are all taxed differently, yet somehow _they_ managed to convert them at practically zero cost for participants. like alchemy.